# How to transform a Crystal Reports table in vertical columns

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I'm facing with the format of the report. I'm trying to transform the next table (returns from a SQL Server database) to the new table format will be displayed in Crystal Reports.

Here is the image

[image]

The only reference which I have is: http://vinodkotiya.blogspot.mx/2011/09/crystal-report-show-data-horizontally.html

But I can't accomplished how to transform it.

I just need to rotate (90 degree) to the table and rotating the second column text.

Answer (score 0):

Use crystal reports cross-tab. It will pivot the data.